# project no longer runs in IIS after moving to visual studio 2022 .net6

Tags: asp.net-core

When trying to run a project in IIS the following error occurs

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.Build'
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List`1 assemblies)
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPartExtensions.<>c.<GetReferencePaths>b__0_0(CompilationLibrary library)
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
         at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetReferencePaths()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
         at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
         at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.LazyMetadataReferenceFeature.get_References()
         at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorProjectEngine.ProcessCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.Process(RazorProjectItem projectItem)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(String relativePath)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.RuntimeViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(String normalizedPath)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(String relativePath)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet`1 expirationTokens, String relativePath, Boolean isMainPage)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, String pageName, Boolean isMainPage)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, String viewName, Boolean isMainPage)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The project runs in IIS in visual studio 2019 but we have moved from .net5 to .net6 and are using visual studio 2022.  The project runs in the old launch profile which I think uses Kestrel but will not run using the IIS launch profile

Comment: How about  your `build` did you able to build the project successfully? It seems you got compilation error as few references seen missing.

Comment: Yep the project builds and runs fine if I just run it with Kestrel and I can build and publish the project. Even with IIS it builds and instead of presenting the login page that error appears instead.  The only change is moving from .net5 to .net6 and upgrading visual studio.  I am thinking I either am missing an SDK,  unlikely or that it's looking in the wrong place for the SDK only when trying to run in debug with IIS support. It might be relevant that this was originally a .netcore 2 project

Comment: I think some `SDK` references not found as the error saying.  Did you checked your installed `SDK` version?

Comment: Finally resolved it although I do not understand the implications of the fix.  I have added the following to the project file <GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `<GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>` to the profject file and it has resolved the issue.